# Running UI Tests on Github Actions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, github-actions, blazor-webassembly, ui-testing

I am trying to create a PoC for running various types of tests for Blazor web app inside Github Actions pipeline. For Unit and Behavior tests it went smooth but when it came to running UI Tests I have encountered a tricky problem - the pipeline is freezing and running inifitely after successful builds. Logs does not give me any clue on what's going on.
I am 100% sure that UI tests are the culprits because after removing their execution step from the .yaml file all works, runs and builds just fine.
I thought that maybe it takes time for the job to boot-up the env for the ui tests to run (no logs about it?) and left it to run for ~30min and it still is in the same place.

I have no clue on what the issue is. Any tip or advice is highly appreciated.

You can check the repo of the project right here:
https://github.com/Stadzior/BlazorApp

Here lays the latest version of the .yaml file:
https://github.com/Stadzior/BlazorApp/blob/master/.github/workflows/dotnet.yml

Here you can see the latest pipeline run:
https://github.com/Stadzior/BlazorApp/runs/2988185445

Here you should be able to see the last run logs:
https://github.com/Stadzior/BlazorApp/blob/master/logs.txt

Comment: Just to check, do you know about [bunit](https://bunit.dev/index.html)?

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, but instead I choose to stick with Nunit, because this PoC is more about creating various types of automated tests for web apps rather than using something created specific for Blazor. Specflow for example is supporting Nunit runner.

Comment: bunit should also run under nUnit. You might give it a try.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Good point, thanks. I will definitely give it a try, but for now my bigger concern is the pipeline in github actions.